# Getting array value in Model.beforeValidate

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to read the value of a checkbox input using the hidden input technique.

[rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box)

From the ActivityOverlord example:

*[views/user/edit.ejs](https://github.com/irlnathan/activityoverlord/blob/master/views/user/edit.ejs)*

```
<% if (user.admin) { %>
    <input type="hidden" name="admin" value="unchecked">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="admin" checked> Admin</label>
<% } else { %>
    <input type="hidden" name="admin" value="unchecked">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="admin"> Admin</label>
<% } %>
```

*[api/models/User.js](https://github.com/irlnathan/activityoverlord/blob/master/api/models/User.js)*

```
  beforeValidate: function (values, next) {
  // renamed in Sails v0.10.x
  // beforeValidation: function (values, next) {

    if (typeof values.admin !== 'undefined') {
      if (values.admin === 'unchecked') {
        values.admin = false;
      } else if (values.admin[1] === 'on') {
        values.admin = true;
      }
    }
     next();
  },
```

In Sails v0.9.x:

`values.admin` is an array of two items.

In Sails v0.10.x:

`values.admin` is `false`.

Should Sails v0.10.x be passing an array to `beforeValidate`?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it this way.
2 HTML-Elements shouldn't have the same name!

Just use it like this:

```
<% if (user.admin) { %>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="admin" checked value="yes"> Admin</label>
<% } else { %>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="admin" value="yes"> Admin</label>
<% } %>
```

than you can make you data before save:

```
var data = {
    name: req.param("username"),
    ....
};

if(req.param("admin") == undefined){
   data.admin = false;
}else{
   data.admin = true;
}
```

than you can use your

```
User.create(data, function(err, success) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually, it appears that two elements with the same name is valid in HTML. However, I used a technique just like yours to solve this.

Comment: i dont say it not valid html - but you shouldn't use this. For many reasons use name more than one make thinks different for you. e.G. using Name-Selectors at Jquery / CSS.

Comment: What about radio buttons? Or two inputs on the same page in different forms? There are plenty of reasons to use the same name in difference circumstances. A blanket rule that says 2 HTML elements shouldn't have the same name is bad advice. Just don't use the same ID and your fine.